# Adding Tag View to Xamarin iOS Application

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

How to have a tag bubbles like in the attached image.I have done this for android using TagView component but not sure how to do it for Xamarin iOS?Any component that I can refer?

[image]

Comment: You can convert ios code to c# and do following link https://github.com/rsattar/CLTokenInputView

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write this custom component yourself .
I would recommend having this designed in XIB/Storyboard and place em at runtime .

very rough idea to create one such subview programmitically could be something like

```
    var myView = new UIView(frame: new CoreGraphics.CGRect(10, 10, 120, 40));
    myView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;

    myView.Layer.CornerRadius = 20;

    var mylabel = new UILabel(frame: new CoreGraphics.CGRect(10, 10, 80, 40));
    mylabel.Text = "MUMBAI";
    myView.Add(mylabel);

    UIButton button = new UIButton();


    button.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(mylabel.Frame.X + mylabel.Frame.Width, 10f, 40, 25);
    button.SetTitle("Title", UIControlState.Normal);
    button.SetBackgroundImage(UIImage.FromBundle("MyImage"),UIControlState.Normal);
    myView.Add(button);

    View.Add(myView);
```

Here frame calculation you need to do ,above are just some sample frame I put .

so ultimately you gonna make such views stack em horizontally ,and when user clicks "x" button , you change the frame with animation .

Answer (score 0):

Try this

https://github.com/nmilcoff/TagsView

> It's super simple to get started:

```
public class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    private TagListView tagsView;

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        // code
        this.tagsView = new TagListView()
        {
            // you can customize properties here!
        };

        this.View.AddSubview(this.tagsView);

        this.View.AddConstraints(        
            // Add your constraints!
        );

        // you can attach a source object to each tag
        var myObject = new MyModel { Title = "I'm a MyModel!" };
        this.tagsView.AddTag(myObject.Title, myObject); 

        // but, if none is provided, it will be the text string 
        this.tagsView.AddTag("I'm a simple tag!"); 
    }
}
```